# JSF2: cannot get data from a HtmlSelectOneMenu in java code

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I am working with MyFaces/Primefaces and I have a problem to get information using ajax.
My page contains a list of panel, inside each panel, the user can select value in a dropdown list, and click on a checkbox which will update its panel (Ajax), I hope I am clear. 
This is my code:

```
<p:panel>
...
<h:selectOneMenu id="beanSet" value="#{myBean.selectedSet}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{langSet}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>


<h:selectBooleanCheckbox 
id="chkbxBeanSet"
value="#{myBean.selectedSetChkbx}" >
    <p:ajax 
    event="click" render="@parent"
    listener="#{action.updateSet}"
    execute="@form"
    immediate="true"
    />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
...
<p:panel>
```

And here my java code:

```
public void updateSet(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
    UIComponent source = (UIComponent)e.getSource();
    System.out.println("Value:"+((HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox)source).getValue());
    UIComponent parent = source.getParent();
    List<UIComponent> children = parent.getChildren();


    HtmlSelectOneMenu lvSet = (HtmlSelectOneMenu)parent.findComponent("beanSet");
    Object value = lvSet.getValue();
    System.out.println("value: " + value);
```

I get the beanSet component, but I can't get its value. As I understand, the getValue calls the getSelectedSet from myBean which is not set (it is in request scope).
I don't understant how I can get the selected value in the dropdown list using ajax.
Another way is to post all the form, but in that case, I have to determine which checkbox was clicked by the user...
If someone can explain me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is `immediate="true"` on the ajax action. This will skip all input components which do **not** have this attribute set during the processing. You should finetune the to-be-processed components in the `process` attribute of `<p:ajax>`. Yes, another culprit is that you used `execute` instead of `process`. The `<p:ajax>` uses `process` where `<f:ajax>` uses `execute`. Also, the way how you accessed the dropdown value is unnecessarily overcomplicated. Just access the `selectedSet` property directly. JSF will set it in the same bean anyway.

So, this should do

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="beanSet" value="#{myBean.selectedSet}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel=" " noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{langSet}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkbxBeanSet" value="#{myBean.selectedSetChkbx}">
    <p:ajax process="@this beanSet" listener="#{action.updateSet}" update="@parent" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

with

```
public void updateSet() {
    System.out.println(selectedSet);
}
```

Note that I omitted `event="click"` from `<p:ajax>`. It's already the default for checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

place this (listener is optional) , the `<f:ajax event="change"` is what you need the most

```
<f:ajax event="change" render="IdsOfComponentToRender" listener="#{myBean.someMethod}" />
```

inside your `<h:selectOneMenu id="beanSet" value="#{myBean.selectedSet}">`

this is the signature of the listener

```
public void someMethod(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) {...
```

b.t.w what is that `updateLvSet` method , and where you call it , and you should not access you data that way...

Comment: For checkboxes and radio buttons it should really be `click`. Better is to just omit the whole `event` attribute altogether. It defaults to `valueChange` which will already generate the right DOM event for the particular component.

Comment: the f:ajax I suggested was told to be placed inside the <h:selectOneMenu (not the checkboxes) that why i wrote event=change (but i guess its still can be removed) ,(bad habit of mine :)

Comment: Hm, I think you misunderstood OP's concrete functional requirement Admittedly his code is confusing, he was a bit careless in simplifying/obfuscating method names; the `updateLvSet` method should actually be `updateSet`, as called by the `<p:ajax>` in the checkboxes.

Comment: @Daniel: sorry for the wrong name of the method, it was an error when copy/paste, I updated